# I need to extract all the characters behind a certain date. using regex

Tags: regex

I need to extract all the characters behind a certain date using regex.

I tried something list before since **I knew the pattern**,

```
(\d{7,8})|([A-Za-z0-9\/]{12})|([0-9\/-]{8,9})
```

as and when I receive **new Invoices** there are different **Invoice numbers** in the **PDF**. One thing that is certain that after the Invoice number there is an **Invoice date** which is in the format **DD/MM/YYYY**

**So I need all the data before this date**

**Sample Data**

```
91504458 26/04/2022
TYRES/REEXPORT 04/07/2022
TYRES/RE-EXPORT 23/09/2022
SAM0112/2022 23/05/2021
020/22-23 17/02/2022
SAM0141/2022 19/03/1975
91/22-23 01/01/2022
SAM0159/2022 15/08/2021
111/22-23 09/09/2021
SAM0106/2022 09/09/2022
017/2022 08/08/2022
91/22-23 07/07/2022
```

**Expected Output Data**

```
91504458
TYRES/REEXPORT
TYRES/RE-EXPORT
SAM0112/2022
020/22-23
SAM0141/2022
91/22-23
SAM0159/2022
111/22-23
SAM0106/2022
017/2022
91/22-23
```

Appreciate your feedback on the same.

Regards,
Manjesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could word boundaries and use an alternation to list and capture the allowed formats in group 1 before matching the date format at the end of the string.

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+(?:[/-][A-Za-z]+)+|\d{7,8}|(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d+|\d+\/\d\d-?\d\d)(?:/\d{4})?)\s+\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ ASCII letters
  - `(?:[/-][A-Za-z]+)+` Repeat 1+ times `-` or `/` and again 1+ letters
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{7,8}` Match 7-8 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[a-zA-Z]+\d+` Match 1+ letters and 1+ digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d+\/\d\d-?\d\d` Match digits `/` and then 2 digits, optional `-` and 2 digits
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `(?:/\d{4})?` Optionally match `/` and 4 digits
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s+\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}` Match 1+ whitespace chars and a date like format
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YmpeLj/1).

Comment: What happens if there are new formats that, I am doing an OCR extraction so  I need all the characters prior to the date.

Comment: @manjeshkumar All characters prior to the date on the same line `^.+?(?=\s*\b\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b)` https://regex101.com/r/v0NY4M/1 Or `\S+(?=\s*\b\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b)` https://regex101.com/r/jdEBS8/1 or `(?<!\S)(?!\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b)\S+(?=\s*\b\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}\b)` https://regex101.com/r/VqL6iP/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dates would always end each row, you could try doing a regex replacement:

```
Find:    \s*\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

Comment: I tried however there is no data is showing. I am using this regex in an OCR environment

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: I don't, we use regex after the data is fetched based on the coordinates and some keywords.